# How can specify the order of displaying shapes when work with open layer map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, openlayers-3, overlapping

I created a map in which consist of different shapes such as 2 circle and one line. The line connects 2 circle Centre.  Even if i have added line first and then the circles, the line always come over the circles.

How can set the display order of these shapes?

Also is there any way to draw a single shape with a circle and line as combined single shape?

```js
function drawCircle(lon, lat) {
    var circleFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]), // Center coordinate
            40000 // Radius in meters
        ),
    });
    circleFeature.setStyle(style1);
    featuresSource.addFeature(circleFeature);
}

// Function to draw a line between two points on the map
function drawLine(startLon, startLat, endLon, endLat) {
    const lineFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([startLon, startLat]),
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([endLon, endLat]),
        ]),
    });
    lineFeature.setStyle(style);

    featuresSource.addFeature(lineFeature);
}

drawCircle(0, 0); // Draw a circle at (0, 0)
drawCircle(1, 1); // Draw another circle at (10, 10)

drawLine(0, 0, 1, 1);
map.addLayer(featuresLayer);
```

Comment: To combine the geometries you could have one feature whose geometry is a geometry collection https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_GeometryCollection-GeometryCollection.html

Comment: Rendering order is determined by the zIndex value of the style https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style-Style.html